# New delegates for carPlay

Tags: swift, ios13, carplay, swift5

I am devleoping navigation app for CarPlay and in iOS 12 there were two methods from CPApplicationDelegate to detect if CarPlay is on:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didConnectCarInterfaceController interfaceController: CPInterfaceController, to window: CPWindow)
```

and

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDisconnectCarInterfaceController interfaceController: CPInterfaceController, from window: CPWindow)
```

In iOS 13 these methods are deprecated and Apple gave new delegate: CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate

I have tried to connect this new delegate CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate to my service that provides all actions for CarPlay but only function I see that can help me is:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration
```

So my question is how to detect if CarPlay is connected and how to provide action for CarPlay launched in one window of new iOS 13 CarPlay.

Answer (score 1):

**---------------------------EDIT------------------------**

In general target's settings check "Supports multiple windows". Then in Info.plist add configuration to your carPlay scene role (CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication), like this:
[image: CarPlay info configuration]
And voilà! 
Your delegate will invoke at

```
func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController, to window: CPWindow)
```

where you can configure your CarPlay controller.

**---------------------------END ------------------------**

I will try something like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, 
                 options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {

    if connectingSceneSession.role == UISceneSession.Role.carTemplateApplication {  
      if let carPlayScene = connectingSceneSession.scene as? CPTemplateApplicationScene {
        carPlayScene.delegate = self
      }
    }
```

and then in your delegate's method you should setup your interface like in iOS12

```
func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController, to window: CPWindow)
```

Don't know if it works, because my CarPlay simulator crashes...

Comment: What version of Xcode you have? And Simulator for iOS 12 or 13? Because for versions lower than Xcode 11.1 CarPlay Simulator was broken ;)

Comment: @impresyjna I am stuck at the same position. did the solution work work?